# Dynamic calculation over dataset by providing logic externally

Tags: java

I am doing some mathematical operation on a data set. As per the requirement of the project, the mathematical formula/logic can be changed at any time. So I am thinking to keep these formals out from the Java code, may be in config file. Below is the sample config file-

`formula.properties` file-

```
formula_a=(a+b)/(7*c+b^2)

formula_b=(a^(1/2)-formula_a*13)

formula_c=spilt_time(formula_b,a,b)
```

`Calculator.java` (A dummy Java file, which may not be correct as Its for demo purpose only)

```
public class Calculator
{
    private final static String FORMULA_A = "formula_a";
    private final static String FORMULA_B = "formula_b";
    private final static String FORMULA_C = "formula_c";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long a = 1738342634L;
        long b = 273562347895L;
        long c = 89346755249L;
        long ansFromFormulaA = applyFormulaFromConfig(FORMULA_A, new long[] { a, b, c });
        long ansFromFormulaB = applyFormulaFromConfig(FORMULA_B, new long[] { a, b, c });
        long ansFromFormulaC = applyFormulaFromConfig(FORMULA_C, new long[] { a, b });
    }

    // spilt_time is used in formula_c
    public static long[] spilt_time(long[] params)
    {
        final long[] split = new long[2];
        // Some logic here which is applied on params array and answer is pushed
        // into split array
        return split;
    }

    private static long applyFormulaFromConfig(String formulaName, long[] params)
    {
        long ans = 0L;
        // Read formula from property file here and apply the params over it and
        // return the answer
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Please help me to design a solution for this.

Comment: You've essentially done nothing.  By now, you should know that SO is not a coding service.

Comment: @SteveP.: I not asking for anybody to Code. I am just asking about the suggestions while designing this framework.

Comment: But that's not really what SO is for.

Comment: Can you please help me to find out the exact place to discuss my question? I thought SO can be helpful for this. Basically I just wanted to know the approach to fulfill my requirement. I'll take care about the coding myself.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure.  Perhaps [Programmers.StackExchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is one:

Define your functions in JavaScript in a separate js-file outside your application. Might look like this:

```
function myFunction1(x, y, z) {
  return x * y + z;
}
```

Now you can evaluate these script via the Java ScriptEngine and call those functions by name, passing them your params.

Have a look: http://www.wondee.info/2013/10/30/the-scriptengine-bindings/

edit:

Propeterties file:

```
function1=x + y * z
function2=x * x
```

read the functions into formula variable... and...

You can put your functions in a String and put it inside a function body like that:

```
String formula = readFromProperties("function1");

String myFunctionScript = String.format("function myFunction(x, y, z) { return %s ;}", formula);
```

Comment: This is working perfectly well (offcourse after having look on the blog :D )
Below are my two points-
(1)The only thing which may create problem in future is the data handling. The mathematical expression is evaluated in JavaScript. For large numbers it is returning double, even though I am proving long as input.
(2) Is it possible to work with property file instead of JS?

Comment: (1) I can't tell you, then you have a look how JavaScript handles long values and operations on that. But you can use Groovy instead of JavaScript and can make your casts etc. within the Groovy language.

Comment: (2) of course you can put them in a property file and but the value String inside of a function body. Look at my edit.

Comment: Hey, for the edit, which you have done in the answer, can you please explain with example? How does it work? Let say x=10,y=1 and z=5. So x*y+z is 15. How I can pass these values? Please explain little more with sample code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That is explained in detail in the blog post..

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but I was asking about the second method i.e. using `String.format`. Can you explain this? How I can pass variable to it?

Comment: you don't need this method just puts the value of the `formula` into the String to replace %s (see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...))

Comment: To invoke the function see the blog post!

Comment: I have already read the blog. My question was _Instead of JavaScript, can we work with properties file?_ Furthermore I was saying that is it possible to write the formula in a properties file and apply this formula in some dataset using Java (No JavaScript) . Remember using JavaScript, all the calculations was performing in JavaScript only. I must be clear now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41039/discussion-between-markusw-and-ravi-joshi)